# How to set Phrase by select value of Select list in Reporting Services

Tags: reporting-services

I have a reporting services, then I have a select field, the user must select a value of this field, so I would like display on a report a "prase" depends of the Selected value.

In the select field I have this option:
All
First
Second
...

If I select "All" option I should be display this phrase:
Uptime by day

If I select another option, I should be display:
Uptime by Fisrt(or second ecc) shift

So I have try to insert this code on General Value expression:

```
="Uptime by "+Parameters!Shift.Label
```

[image]

Comment: I think that is an error, I have just change image

Comment: Not working because, I want the message is Dinamyc. If I select 'All' option I display "Uptime by Day", if Ii select another one option the messege is "Uptime by First Shift" for example.
I think if I insert an IF condition in this expression

Comment: Yes, an IF condition is exactly what you want.   Do you not know how to do that?

Comment: I don't now a sintax of it (in Reporting service)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this as your expression:

```
="Uptime by " + iif(Parameters!Shift.Label.Equals("All"),"Day",Parameters!Shift.Label + " shift")
```